# How to find range between every two corresponding elements of vector in Octave/MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, octave

Say, I have two vectors:

```
a = [1 , 2 , 3]
b = [4 , 5 ,6]
```

I want to build a matrix from a and b like this:

```
c = [1:4 , 2:5 , 3:6].
```

i.e.

```
c = |1 2 3 4|
    |2 3 4 5|
    |3 4 5 6|
```

I basically want something like element wise range of numbers in a and b. How can I do it? I don't want to use any loops.

Comment: I reckon what you want can be done with `bsxfun`, though beware: as soon as your ranges are not equal in length they cannot fit into the same matrix. (I leave the `bsxfun` solution to someone with experience in that)

Comment: Is there a case where: (1) you have unequal lengths of each vector?... that is, are you **guaranteed** that each vector in the matrix has the same length? (2) What do you do in the case where you don't have valid ranges?... for example, what if you had 1 for `a` and -1 for `b`?

Comment: @rayryeng Yes , it is guaranteed that the length of ranges will be same and that an element in a will be smaller than the corresponding element in b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your comments, you can intelligently use a call to [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
>> c = bsxfun(@plus, a.', 0:(b(1)-a(1)));
>> c

c =

     1     2     3     4
     2     3     4     5
     3     4     5     6
```

So how does this code work?  `bsxfun` stands for **B**inary **S**ingleton E**X**pansion **FUN**ction.  If you're familiar with the `repmat` function, it essentially replicates matrices and vectors under the hood so that both inputs you're operating on have the same size.  In this case, what I'm doing is specifying `a` as the first input and a vector from `0` up to `b(1)-a(1)` as the second input.  Note that `a` **transposed**.  By doing this `bsxfun` automatically **broadcasts** each input so that the inputs match in dimension.  Specifically, the first input is a column vector `a` and so this gets repeated and stacked horizontally for as many times as there are in the vector `0:(b(1)-a(1))`.  Similarly, the vector `0:(b(1)-a(1))` gets stacked horizontally for as many values as there are in `a`.  Once you're done here, you simply add the two matrices together element-wise by the `@plus` function, and your result follows.

---

Given the fact that range of each pair of `a` and `b` are the same, all you have to do is figure out the difference between the first element in `b` with the first element in `a`, then create a vector from `0` up to `b(1)-a(1)` and add this to every value in `a`.  This results in a matrix where each row has the desired range you want.  In this case, I would argue that you don't need `b` at all.  You just have to define **how many** elements you want in each row and you can disregard `b`.  In your case, you want four elements per row, so I would do:

```
>> n = 4;
>> c = bsxfun(@plus, a.', 0:n-1);
>> c

c =

     1     2     3     4
     2     3     4     5
     3     4     5     6
```

Comment: This actually does the work. Can you please explain what exactly you have done.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood your logic!

Comment: @AdityaNaidu - Try now :) I added more details.  Hope that helps!